# Add suffix to each lines containing specific word

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sh

I have 2 files:

file1

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

file2 (might not be sorted in same order)

```
ghi:Checked
def:Checked
```

I would like to create a file like this:

```
abc
def:Checked
ghi:Checked
jkl
```

Is there a way to do that in shell ? I would like not to change the sorting order of my file1

Comment: Your sample files are  sorted. If they were not, would sorting be allowed?

Comment: Strictly speaking, this question is about a left join, not an inner join, so maybe it makes sense to leave it open.

Comment: The duplicate has several answers which do not require sorting.

Comment: @Alex: For performance reason, I would put each _Checked_ key from file2 into an associative array and then loop through file1, and test whether the key is in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#! /bin/bash

exec < file1

while read -r id; do
  check=$(grep "^$id:" file2)
  if (($? == 0)); then
    echo "$check"
  else
    echo "$id"
  fi
done
```

Update: alternative implementation, which reads file2 just once.

```
#! /bin/bash

file2=$(grep ':Checked$' file2)

exec < file1

while read -r id; do
  check=$(grep "^$id:" <<< $file2)
  if (($? == 0)); then
    echo "$check"
  else
    echo "$id"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Works well, i would have preferred not to have to create a loop myself tho

Comment: Can also be `if check=$(grep "^$id:" file2.txt); then ...` without the need for `(($? == 0))`, just my two cents.

Comment: @ceving : Fine, if `file1` is not too big, because you are creating one child process for each line in file1.

Comment: @user1934428 Creating child processes for almost everything is the way shell scripting works. If you do not like it, use Perl instead.

Comment: @ceving : Well, you can solve this in bash *without* having a child process. I am not against child processes as such, I just try to avoid a large amount of unnecessary ones.

Comment: @user1934428 The problem is not the child process. The problem is that for each line in file1 all lines of file2 are read. If file2 is big, this might get slow. In order to solve this, you have to keep file2 in memory. But this is just another you pay. If you re-read file2, you pay with CPU time. If you keep file2 in memory, you pay with memory usage. Which way is better, depends on the requirements.

Comment: @ceving : That's why I suggested in my comment to use an associative array for the content of file2. If the files in question are so big that we run into memory problems, the whole algorithm needs to be reconsidered anyway.....

Comment: @user1934428 The memory footprint of my first version does not depend on the size of the files. The files can be as big as you can buy storage. Only the second version will fail, if file2 is bigger than the memory.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```sh
$ join -a 1 -t: <( sort file1 ) <( sort file2 )
abc
def:Checked
ghi:Checked
jkl
```

Comment: Interesting, but it doesn't work if file2 isn't sorted

Comment: @Alex does it work if you sort them? I've edited my answer to incorporate that.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but in my case its would be better to not sort it